# How do I model forces on a zipline pulley?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, string

[image]

I am trying to model this dynamic system of a pulley with a weight attached to it traveling down a rope. I am using the assumption of a massless pulley and rope but I am assuming the rope will stretch when weighted and therefore at any given time, the FBD of the system will look something like this. Now in a classic physics problem for example when there is a massless, frictionless pulley hanging from a line that goes around it with tension T, you can just sum the two tensions pointing upward and the weight of the mass pulling down, but I am having a hard time convincing myself I could use the same approach in this situation. In short, how do I draw the forces acting on the pulley?

Comment: Update:
I am starting to believe that maybe just summing all the forces would be the correct approach, unless I am missing something that has to do with the fact that a mass will be moving along with the pulley. I guess one thing I neglected to add is the acceleration of the mass at any given time. One thing I am running into now though is I don't know ho to calculate the the tension.

Comment: To calculate the tension, use Newton's laws in two dimensions: $\sum F_x = m a_x$, $\sum F_y = 0$. There is positive acceleration in the $\hat{x}$-direction since the zipline user will be moving forward. There is also a net torque on the pulley, since the pulley is rotating with an increasing angular velocity. $\sum \tau = I \alpha = ( \frac{1}{2} m r^2 ) (\frac{a}{r})$

Comment: @wyphan OP specified pulley is massless.

Comment: Ah, right, missed that tiny bit of information. Then, no need to bother about the net torque on the pulley.

Comment: I will just add that I finished the model and it seems to be at least somewhat representative of what I was going for. I ended up modeling the entire rope as a spring with a constant k. Using the pythagorean theorem I calculated the elongation of the rope at any given point thus the tension was equal to k*delta + initial tension. I solved the system in matlab as a system of two second order equations as well as two first order equations calculating the motion in x and y individually.